# load json data from category dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, json, web

I am trying to load json data from a dropdown category List which result would be displayed in an HTML div area. 
The dropdown i as folows
  <

```
div id="content-1">
       <select>
    <optgroup label="Games">
        <option>PC</option>
        <option>Wii</option>
        <option>Xbox</option>
        <option>PS3</option>
        <option>PS4</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Consoles">
        <option>PS3</option>
        <option>PS4</option>
        <option>PS3</option>
        <option>Xbox</option>
    </optgroup>
   </select>
 </div>
```

The options are present in the json file declared as category, as shown in the  PRproducts.json file

```
{
"games":
 [
    {
    "id":"P001",
    "title":"Call of Duty - Ghosts",
    "category":"PC",
    "genre":"Action Multiplayer Game",
    "developed":"Ubisoft",
    "imgpath":"images/thumb/Call of Duty Ghosts(PC).jpg",
    "released": "November 2013",
    "price":45.00,
    "quantity":4
    },
    {
    "id":"P002",
    "title":"Assassins Creed IV - Black Flag",
    "category":"PC",
    "genre":"Action Adventure Game",
    "developed":" Ubisoft",
    "imgpath":"images/thumb/Assasins Creed Black Flag (PC).jpg",
    "released": "October 2013",
    "price":45.00,
    "quantity":4
    },
    {
        "id":"P003",
    "title":"Total War: Rome II",
    "category":"PC",
    "genre":"Strategy Game",
    "developed":"Creative Assembly",
    "imgpath":"images/thumb/Rome Total War II.jpg",
    "released": "September 2013",
    "price":42.00,
    "quantity":4
     },
     {
     "id":"P004",
    "title":"Battlefield 4",
    "category":"PC",
    "genre":"First Person Action Game",
    "developed":"Electronic Arts",
    "imgpath":"images/thumb/Battlefield 4.jpg",
    "released":"October 2013",
    "price":39.99,
    "quantity":4
    },
    {
        "id":"P005",
    "title":"Call of Duty - Black Ops",
    "category":"Wii",
    "genre": "Action Game",
    "developed":"Ubisoft",
    "imgpath":"images/thumb/Call of Duty Black Ops(Wii).jpg",
    "released": "November 2013",
    "price":45.00,
    "quantity":4
    }
 ]
}
```

While the below is the code that i have to display all the products when the page is opened

```
var objGames;   

 $(document).ready(function(){

    /*alert("before getJSON");*/

     $.getJSON('PCproducts.json',null, function(data){

        /*alert("help");*/

        objGames = data;


        var output = '<div id="row">';

        /*  var count = 1;*/
            $.each(objGames.games, function (key, val) {

                output += '<div id="Container">';
                output += '<div id="img-area"><img id="img" src="'+val.imgpath+'" alt="'+ val.title +'" /></div>';
                output += '<div id="Box1">';
                output += '<h2>' + val.title + '</h2>';
                output += '<p>Category:' + val.category + '</p>';
                output += '<p>Developer:' + val.developed + '</p>';
                output += '<p>Genre:' + val.genre + '</p>';
                output += '<p>Released on:' + val.released + '</p>';
                output += '<p>Euro: ' + val.price + '</p>';
                output += '<p>Quantity: ' + val.quantity + '</p>';
                output += '<p><input data-item="'+ val.id +'" type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" /></p>'
                output += '</div>';
                output += '</div>';
                /*if(count%2 == 0){
                  output += '</div><div id="row">'
                  }
                  count++;*/

            });
             output += '</div>';

            /*output += '</div>';*/
            $('#content-2-1').html(output);     // replace all existing content
```

My problem is that i am confused on how to make the Jquery code to display the required items, that is if for example PC option is pressed the PC games are shown only and if the Wii option is pressed the Wii games are shown only and so on, and not all the products are displayed. 
Can someone please help me out in my problem as i am really stuck and do not know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but here is one way to hide options:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kb7zL/

HTML:

```
PS3<input type="checkbox" name="ps3" checked> PS4<input type="checkbox" name="ps4" checked>
<select>
    <optgroup class="ps3">
        <option value="Crash Bandicoot">Crash</option>
        <option value="Metal Gear">MGS</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="ps4">
        <option value="Crash Bandicoot">Crash</option>
        <option value="Metal Gear">MGS</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    var target = $(this),
        name = target.attr('name');

    $('.hideStuff').removeClass('hideStuff');

    if(!target.is(':checked')){
        $('optgroup.'+name).children().addClass('hideStuff');
    }
})
```

CSS:

```
.hideStuff{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` to get the selected value of dropdown. Assuming your dropdown is given id `#cat-select`:

```
var selected_category = $('#cat-select').val();
```

Then in your display loop, skip the element if it doesn't belong to filtered category

```
$.each(objGames.games, function (key, val) {
  if(val.category != selected_category) {
    continue;
  }
  ...
  // further code to render here
}
```